# Mixpanel funnels based on people properties

Tags: geolocation, analytics, tracking, metrics, mixpanel

I'm successfully tracking events and creating people profiles using Mixpanel in Ruby.

I can create an event

`tracker.track(123456712,'NewArrival', { gender: 'male', ad_version: 1 })`

In this case, when I go into the Mixpanel analytics, I can segment my funnel based on the gender property above I passed in above.

I can also create a person profile:

`tracker.people.set(1234560, {
        '$first_name'       => 'Stacy',
        '$last_name'        => 'Smith',
        '$phone'            => '5555555555',
        'Favorite Color'    => 'blue'
    })`

In which case I can go into the People tab and see some additional properties about Stacy such as her city and country data, which Mixpanel automatically takes care of.

What I'd like to do is access the city and country data from the funnel builder interface, so that I can see how my conversion funnels vary by geography.  However, I can't see anyway to filter based on this data inside the funnel (the built-in properties do not appear).

Is there a way to do this easily?  I guess I can implement my own geo-lookup and pass this data as properties, but given Mixpanel already has this this doesn't seem optimal.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had the same problem. I could never find a way to do it short of storing the data I wanted and adding it to the event properties..

Answer (score 0):

People Properties are only for use in the People Analytics reports (bottom set of reports in Mixpanel).

Super Properties are what you use for the engagement (i.e. funnel/segmentation) reports.
You need to Register a Super Property at the same time as the People Property in order to have it show up in all reports.

See Mixpanel Documentation on this: https://mixpanel.com/docs/managing-users/managing-user_specific-properties